# Spring Validation Displaying Custom Message

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Validation in Spring 3.x using @Valid annotation:
Below is snippet from the messages_en.properties. I have a form having Username and Password field. When user does not enter anything in Username field, it displays both these messages one below other.

```
NotEmpty.loginBean.username=Username cannot be Empty
Size.loginBean.username=Size must between 5 to 50 characters.
```

Any HTML tag given in the message.properties is not interpreted.

```
NotEmpty.loginBean.username=<li>Username cannot be Empty</li>
```

Above would display <li> as it is. 
Questions:
1) Is there any ways to interpret HTML tag and display its output?
2) Can i show single message though both validation fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad. 1) Yes, use `htmlEscape="false"`:

```
<form:errors path="nip" cssClass="error" htmlEscape="false" />
```

Ad. 2) This is actually JSR303's Achilles' heel - it can be done, but is neither easy nor clean (see [this issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/BVAL-255)). Order of validating each annotated field is undefined, so trick is to use `@GroupSequence` and custom groups like described [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1007328) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535759/if-i-use-two-custom-annotations-in-jsr-303-how-to-stop-validation-for-second-ann).

Alternative solution would be to use [custom annotation with @ReportAsSingleViolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7600343/708434), but it will not distinct NotEmpty and Size errors as it'll have its own error message.